# New Wave-ish story, Experimental school taken over by children, teacher forced to write memoirs repeatedly on chalkboard

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in a science fiction anthology in the 1980s, but it's probably from the 1970s.  A female teacher at an experimental boarding school (a school where children are strongly discouraged against using words like "bad") is obsessed (inappropriately) with a new (young) male student, who is from a tougher environment than the rest of the students.  I think the teacher tries to seduce him, but he's more interested in taking over the school (leading the other students in a coup); he shows no sexual interest in her, to her disappointment. The story ends with the teacher revealing that she's been writing her memoirs on the chalkboards, and will be required to write them a hundred times. Very thin on the SF elements, but definitely published in an SF anthology.  I thought it might have been "The Teacher" from "Orbit 18" but it's not that.

@jo1storm suggests that the children have mind control or other powers, and I think that's probably right; it's just that that element is (if I recall correctly) suggested, rather than revealed (because the main character never quite figures it out?).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: Children have special powers, like X-men. The teacher is implied to be mind controlled (her brain is made fuzzy, that's why she is so focused on writing memoirs on the chalkboard instead of fighting back). I vaguely remember reading the story but can't remember when and where.